# Disable Chrome new tab thumbnail

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I was wondering if there is a way to block Google Chrome from using certain pages as thumbnail. I'm asking since I'm building a website containing some sensitive information. In the current implementation the sensitive information can be read in the thumbnail.

Comment: What do you mean by 'thumbnail'?

Comment: On the new tab page, Chrome uses 8 little thumbnails to show your 8 most visited pages. (http://i.imgur.com/RTvdGze.png)

Answer (score 2):

Install "empty new tab page" plugin from Google Chrome Web Store

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/empty-new-tab-page/dpjamkmjmigaoobjbekmfgabipmfilij

It works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide/disable the Most Visited thumbnails, the "Empty New Tab Page" extension is not the best solution because then you'll also be missing all other elements (mainly the search bar, Google logo and the bookmarks bar).

To hide the Most Visited thumbnails only, use the [Hide Most Visited Pages Reloaded](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-most-visited-pages-r/dhphmpoekpoecdbjeionimpiceigkeil?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) extension. The nice thing about this extension is that it allows you to show or hide each element of the Home/New Tab page to your taste.

Answer (score -2):

Incognito mode will prevent Chrome from caching the page.

Comment: Well, I want to that for my users (if it's even possible).

Answer (score -2):

use meta noindex / nofollow and / or htpasswd